# Returning the size of a record (in bytes) from OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

OrientDB supports various methods to get the length of a collection or the length of a string, but I'm trying to determine the total size of a record in bytes. I can't find anything in the documentation or elsewhere that addresses this. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Thx

Comment: @MichelaBonizzi: 2.2.29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer from OrientDB's Luigi...*

Create a function called "recordSize" (or something) with one input param (in this case `record`): `return record.getSize();`

Use it like this: `select recordSize(@this) from...`